# If the page=number doesn't exist, return an empty array instead of Http404 django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p7GT.png)

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/product-list/?category_id__in=1,2,3&search=&page_size=10&page=1

Hello everyone! I'm filtering by Category_id, search, and page number using the URL, but doestn exist page number, it returns me HTTP 404. I need it to return an empty array instead of HTTP 404. Thanks in advance

To return an empty array instead of raising a Http404 exception when a page number does not exist in Django Rest Framework

```
pagination.py

# Pagination function
class ProductPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 3
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    page_query_param = 'page'
    max_page_size = 10000

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'first': self.get_first_link(),
                'last': self.get_last_link(),
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'total': self.page.paginator.count,
            'current_page_number': self.page.number,
            'per_page': self.page_size,
            'total_pages': self.page.paginator.num_pages,
            'results': data,

        })
```

views.py

```
# Product API View
class ProductListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
    pagination_class = ProductPagination
    search_fields = ['name', 'category__name', 'brand__name']`
```

```
Thanks
```